# Create scalar function with declared variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, user-defined-functions

I have a verify simple query in which I have a variable declared. I would like to create a scalar function that automatically converts whatever I write into the variable, into my finished string:

```
declare @name varchar(100) = 'firstnameLastname'

select @name + '@email.com'
```

My goal is to use this function with a random string which converts it automatically into my Email String. For example:

```
select udfEmailConversion('RobertSequel')
```

and it should automatically return:

```
RobertSequel@email.com
```

How can create a scalar function when I have variables declared in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about how to define a function, the syntax looks like:

```
create function udfEmailConversion (
    @base nvarchar(255)
) 
returns nvarchar(255)
as 
begin
     return @base + '@email.com'
end;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon! Thank you! And how would it look like if @name would be a column in a table?

Comment: @not_ur_avg_cookie . . . Then you would call the function in a `select` query referring to that table and column.